# fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource and fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, fopen, fclose

```
private function WriteFile($file,$mode,$content){
    $handle = fopen($file, $mode);
    fwrite($handle, $content);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

this is my code and giving me the error

> fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in and
>   fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   directory

Comment: Use the debugger. Is parameter 1 a resource? (Also, what language is this?)

Comment: This is because `fopen` fails to open your file.

Comment: @RaymondChen this is a PHP script for PV traffic

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ but the file directory is simply good.

Comment: Please check the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives. Otherwise, you're coding in the dark.

Comment: @MamunurRashid The error message is clear enough. Take a look the answer I made.

Comment: It really looks like you're recreating the `file_put_contents` wheel here anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `fopen` fails to open your file: the error message indicates that a `boolean` is given instead of a `resource`.

From PHP documentation:

> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

You should check the value of `$handle`.

```
$handle = fopen($file, $mode);
if(is_resource($handle)) {
    fwrite($handle, $content);
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // Handle error if needed
}
```

Comment: Checking that it isn't false, as in `if ($handle) {/*...*/}`, is enough.