# warning with fwrite() function in php

Tags: php, fwrite, fread, fseek, fclose

i use Netbeans IDE with XAMPP in MAC OS 10.15
i get this warnings when i compiling this code

```
<?php
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing to tempfile");
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 1024);
fclose($temp); 
?>
```

becuz i get this error:

```
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...
fseek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...
fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...
fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...
```

whats a problem? help me please. tnx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource and fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555611/fwrite-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-and-fclose-expects-parameter-1-to)

Comment: It would appear that `tmpfile()` failed hence returning FALSE which is your boolean

Comment: :( Did you forget to call fopen() before fwrite()???